# Union operation in foreach object array (es6)?

Tags: foreach, ecmascript-6, union

I have to concat arrays in my object array with union operation. I have an object like below:

```
let appointments = [{
  Name: "doctor",
  Detail: [Place: "A street", Time: {
    "10:10",
    "15:00",
    "15:30"
  }]
}, {
  Name: "hairdresser",
  Detail: [Place: "B street", Time: {
    "10:10",
    "15:00",
    "15:30"
  }]
}, {
  Name: "hairdresser",
  Detail: [Place: "C street", Time: {
    "10:10",
    "15:00",
    "15:30",
    "14:00"
  }]
}]
```

I want to concat time property at all details in one array with union.
It should be like below: How can I do that?

```
Time:["10:10","15:00","15:30","14:00"]
```

Comment: You have lost "14:00" while editing.

Answer (score 3):

Extract all times to a new array, flatten it, then make it a Set to remove duplicates.

```js
let appointments= [{Name:"doctor", Time:["10:10","15:00","15:30"]},{Name:"hairdresser", Time:["15:00","15:30"]}, {Name:"dentist", Time:["14:00"]}]

const time = [...new Set(appointments
  .map(({Time}) => Time)
  .reduce((all, item) => [...all, ...item]))]

console.log(time)
```

Comment: If "time" is object can I handle like Time.blabla property like this?@Yury Tarabanko

Comment: @ale Do you mean this `Time: {
    "10:10",
    "15:00",
    "15:30"
  }`? Then no, this is invalid syntax. Your original post had arrays.

Comment: yes that time. In my real example I realized that time is also object array. property of time should be concat and reduce. Should I convert to nested map and reduce operation.

Comment: @ale I'd say yes. You'll need to somehow extract times as an array. But anyway you can't have something like this `{Time: { "10:10", "15:00", "15:30" }}` because this is **not** valid javascript.

Comment: no no I mean it is like that:
Time: { hours:["10:10", "15:00", "15:30"],days:["sunday","monday"] }
hours is important for me 
all Time.hours should be concat

Comment: @ale If you ignore days that would simply be one more level of destructuring `.map(({ Time: { hours } }) => hours)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    let appointments= [
    {Name:"doctor", Time:["10:10","15:00","15:30"]},
    {Name:"hairdresser", Time:["15:00","15:30"]},
    {Name:"dentist", Time:["14:00"]}
    ]
    var timeArray=[];
    var lastArray=[]
    appointments.forEach(function(item){
    return timeArray.push(item.Time)
    })
    for (var i = timeArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = timeArray[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if(lastArray.indexOf(timeArray[i][j])===-1){
        lastArray.push(timeArray[i][j])
    }
    }
    }
    console.log(lastArray)
    </script>
```

This is just one method of doing it.